# SQL Server - Is there a way to see how often a column gets queried?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to see what columns in a database are queried most often or how frequently a query appears in a query? Ad-hoc, stored procedure, view, etc.

Comment: You could potentially do that with SQL Profiler

Comment: Your best bet may be to look into the audit feature SQL has: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If your sql code writers are in the habit of using "*" as the column list, I'm not certain your goal can be achieved.